# Trying to add Android Studio Project to github

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I'm trying to add an Android Studio Project to github, however only the gitattributes and .gitignore files were added to the repository and it won't seems to add the actual project files. Doing VCS->Git->Add does nothing and Committing just gives me a message that no changes are detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably having some issues with your `.gitignore` - it seems to be ignoring too much things.

The best you can do is go to the terminal and run `git status --ignored` to see if this is the case. If it is, review the contents of your `.gitignore` and try again.